# Adding Firebase Cloud Messaging to iOS MDM

Tags: ios, mdm, firebase-cloud-messaging

when it is required to add Firebase into iOS, it is necessary to provide the bundle ID. I would like to know whether Firebase can be added to MDM client in iOS. In that case, anyone knows the Bundle ID of iOS MDM client? Are there any additional implementation steps than adding Firebase to any other iOS apps?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to send Push Notification to iOS devices using new Firebase Cloud Messaging service (renamed from Google Cloud Messaging), then you can add firebase to your iOS project.

Am not sure whats your question regarding adding to MDM, it doesn't work that way.

you can check out how it works and how to set it up for iOS projects using the following link,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging